# Error: "embedded nul in string" when collecting word count in sparklyr in R

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, error-handling, sparklyr

I have a Spark data frame (with the "sparklyr" package in R) with the word count of several words from 3 data sources (news, blogs, and twitter). I'm trying to use `collect()` to copy the data from Spark to R's memory.

After counting the words with several functions for text mining with sparklyr, I have the following:

```
> word_count

# Source:     spark<?> [?? x 3]
# Groups:     dataset
# Ordered by: desc(n)
   dataset word        n
   <chr>   <chr>   <int>
 1 news    said   250414
 2 blogs   one    127526
 3 twitter like   122384
 4 twitter get    112510
 5 twitter love   106122
 6 twitter good   100844
 7 blogs   like   100105
 8 twitter day     91559
 9 blogs   time    90609
10 twitter thanks  89513
# ... with more rows
```

Now, if I try to use `collect()`, I get the following error:

```
> full_word_count <- collect(word_count)

Error in RecordBatch__to_dataframe(x, use_threads = option_use_threads()) : 
  embedded nul in string: '\0\0ul437'
```

After researching a little bit ([Beginner trying to read a CSV with R: Embedded nul in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459264/beginner-trying-to-read-a-csv-with-r-embedded-nul-in-string)) it seems that:

> The error message states that you have embedded a nul char...: \0
> denotes ASCII byte == 0, which is forbidden in an R string
> (internally, it denotes the end of a string).

Some people already asked something similar ([Sparklyr "embedded nul in string" when collecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341000/sparklyr-embedded-nul-in-string-when-collecting)), but they received no clear answer.

**How can I get rid of this "nul" in the string? Can dplyr help me with this? Is there any function in sparklyr to tackle this issue?**

I'm trying to collect this Spark data frame to R's internal memory to finally export it as a CSV or XLSX file for further analysis.

Thanks!

Comment: May you try if `iconv(x, "latin1", "ASCII", "?")` on the column that contain the `nul` string to see if this get rid of the special character. This is what I used when work in with MSSQL database that encounter similar error 3 years ago.

Comment: Thanks @SinhNguyen . I'm trying to use that function but it takes a character vector as its input, and so far I haven't found a way to convert a column from the Spark data frame into some sort of character vector...

Answer (score 0):

R is a bit particular about nuls.

you can replace the nuls ("\0") on the Spark side before collecting. The offending string is most likely in your `word` column:

```
word_count %>%
replace(word, "\0","") %>%
sdf_collect()
```

alternatively, you can enter into the encoding/decoding hell that is associated with text mining :P

Comment: I had to use `replace(word, "\\0", "")` when doing this with sparklyr.